# My friend is in Göttingen for the next few weeks; how can they enquire as to how/where to see and hear a pipe organ?

Tags: germany, music

My friend is on business in Göttingen and is free on the weekends.

How and where can they enquire about having the experience of seeing and hearing a pipe organ? Ideally in Göttingen as they would like to avoid travel if possible.

It could be a concert or just at/after the end of Sunday services; whatever is possible.

Comment: What have they tried already? Tourist information office? Calling the main church(es)?

Comment: @Willeke the idea is only about 15 minutes old. I think they can do some of that no problem, but it's possible that pipe-organ-listening is not the main reason that tourists go to Göttingen. On the other hand, experienced pipe-organ-tourists may be able to contribute here in some ways beyond looking up the tourist information office, provided there are any of those active here :-)

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161861/how-to-find-the-locations-of-europes-largest-pipe-organs

Comment: Could you make the question more straightforward by removing the "asking for a friend" touch?

Comment: @Bergi the truth reflects the particulars of the situation; we're not in constant contact; I'll take the results, check the links and the map, and then advise them accordingly. I've done my best to reflect the exact nature of the problem for which I'm seeking assistance. After asking several thousand Stack Exchange questions in a  variety of sites I've found that a correct and complete statement of the problem is always the best way to go, and I don't think it's ever wise to advise users to do otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a calendar, although it's a bit limited and nothing is near Gottingen https://bund-deutscher-orgelbaumeister.de/orgelkonzerte/

Here is what's happening in the local churches. https://kirchenmusik-goettingen.wir-e.de/aktuelles They actually did have a "organ discovery day" but it was in October. Your friend can just call them up and ask.

Jacobi church music calendar: https://www.jacobikantorei.de/index.php/konzerte/konzerte

Next week there is a nice concert in Hannover: https://www.marktkirche-hannover.de/termine/inhalt?id=333901

Very interesting  organ in Kassel https://www.musik-martinskirche.de/

Your friend can also just attend any church services: If the church has an organ, it will be played during the service!

Corona rates are spiking in Germany and restrictions are increasing again, so some scheduled events may get cancelled or moved.

Best strategy: just keep your eyes on local announcements and ask at the local churches.

Comment: This is all wonderful advice and excellent sourcing; thank you! I may be able to get them to hang out at the end of a service and listen as the doors open, I'm pretty sure that right now both being shy and unfamiliar with Christian church etiquette and cautious of large groups of people they won't be venturing inside to enjoy a service.

Comment: There are two major churches in Germany "Evangelisch" (protestant) and Katholisch (Catholic). Evangelisch is significantly more relaxed and has less rituals. Your friends would be very welcome to just hang out. If in doubt, just ask, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree with Hilmar. Your friend will probably be asked to show vaccination status, that is an opportunity to mention that he/she is not part of the congregation and just there for the music. People will be helpful. Stay quiet and respectful. stand when *everybody* stands, sit when *everybody* sits, don't go forward for the Communion if there is one. Consider to donate a few Euros (2€ to 5€) at the exit, that is not directly going to fund the church services but it is for one of their causes. And go soon, incidence rates are rising and won't get much better before spring.

Comment: Churches in Germany have different practices and rules for attending a service, some require a test or a seat reservation. Your friend should check the church website or announcement board.

Comment: @o.m. Regarding standing/sitting/kneeling: churches are usually quite open to interested visitors and do not require them to actively participate in acts of worship. It's OK to just sit and watch.

Comment: @user24582, following the motions of the crowd avoids standing out and may be more comfortable in that regard. Personally I don't think it is active participation, unlike speaking the Lord's Prayer or the Creed along with the congregation.

Comment: @o.m. Half the congregation might just follow the motions :-) and that's OK. But the motions were created to follow the biblical example of worship, e.g. to kneel before God. I just don't want anyone to act against their conscience.

Comment: I'm an atheistic heathen :-) and I have no problems sitting through a service if needed without it being disrespectful to the church or myself. Church attendance in Germany is in steady decline and they are probably happy about everyone who shows up on a normal Sunday.